# Startup Application command flags?

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I'm trying to add an application for startup that runs a program with a flag. I entered `xpad -h` and `xpad --h` into the command line. Xpad is a sticky note application, and the `-h` flag tells it to hide the windows but still keep an indicator open. Whenever I login, my computer will open Xpad but won't hide the windows, which I believe means that the flag is ignored. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I added `/usr/bin/wuala -silent` to startup applications and it works like it should.

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/xpad -h` and still nothing. Would a script work better?

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work with `xpad`. A script might be a possible workaround - why not try it?

Comment: I created the script `#!/bin/bash

xpad -h` and that still does not work. Meh, it's not too tough to just close the window on login.

Comment: Running the script doesn't depend on autostart - it doesn't work to start Xpad hidden. Possibly you should [ask a question on launchpad or file a bug](https://launchpad.net/xpad) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix the problem I had with Xpad. I created a script:

`#!/bin/bash`

`sleep 3`

`xpad --hide &`

and now it works. It was adding `sleep 3` that let it work finally. Any lower value does not seem to work.

Comment: It is a known (and by now) registered bug. Thanks for giving your solution. Here you can find other possibilities for other situations.

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/xpad/+bug/405314
Blueprint for future fix: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/xpad/+spec/xpad-autostart